# Set of numbers statistically higher than other

Tags: hypothesis-testing, discrete-data

I have a set of numbers (number of publications for each year of one person). I don't know the exact distribution. Now I also have another set of numbers to compare that to (number of publications for each year of the same person during another time period).
I'm interested whether the person has a higher publishing rate in that second time period.

Can someone point me to a simple method I should use to determine the probability that one set of numbers is usually higher than the other? (ideally a source where I can find all the maths)

Does it make sense to first sum up all publication numbers per year to get an overall for each period or do I lose information this way?

Can I get more precise results if I assume a known distribution? Any suggestions which distribution makes sense for publication rates?

Comment: You appear to have a census of the person's number of publications. Why do you wish to use statistics?

Comment: I need a solid statement about evidence whether the publication rate has really increased.

Comment: I suggest you look at the [Mann–Whitney–Wilcoxon rank test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U), since it seems particularly suited to your question. There also are [entries on Stack Exchange](-withney).

Comment: Does it matter whether the person was first author or not?

Comment: @Michelle: for the moment in don't distinguish whether he was first author. there are too few data points anyway.

Comment: @Xian: Sounds pretty interesting! Maybe exactly what I need. I'll have to go through it. Will give me probabilities? Want to post it as an answer?

Comment: Regardless of which method is used to decide the issue, the results of such a calculation are highly suspect.  Publication rates depend on things beyond the author's control as well, and an author could well have a bunch of papers appear in one year (because of delays in editorial processes) and possibly none in another year.  This is the kind of stuff that department heads and deans love to use to justify a decision (e.g. extra raise or no raise) that has been reached on other grounds. The OP should ask what result is wanted by the client and choose a test that will give that result.

Comment: @Dilip: That's certainly true, but rather than not getting anywhere, I rather get a result keeping in mind that noise factors are possible. Basically that's all the data I have and I want to find trends by some simple rule. Actually I much more want to disprove false trends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Counts are often modeled as coming from a Poisson distribution.  You could do a Poisson regression with a variable representing time period as the predictor variable (this assumes that there is no dependence on time within group).

Another approach that does not assume a given distribution (but does assume that each dataset is representative of the respective time period) is a permutation test.  The null hypothesis is that there is no difference between the 2 times periods, so the only difference is due to the randomness of which observation was assigned to which time period.  Basically you choose a summary (mean, median, other) and compute the difference between the measures for the 2 groups, then you randomly permute the observations between the 2 groups and recompute the difference, do this a bunch of times and compare the difference in the original data to the distribution of the permuted differences.

Comment: How does Poisson regression and the permutation test compare to the MWW U-Test mentioned by Xian? Can it give me better results? (a have very small sample sizes)

Comment: The MWW U-test is actually a special case of the permutation test, so if you use the same U-statistic and enough permutations you will get the same answer, however the general permutation test allows you to use a statistic that may be more meaningful (or at least easier to explain).  I don't know for certain, but I would expect that if the data really comes from a Poisson then the poisson regression should be a little more powerful (but it would not be as good if the Poisson is a poor approximation).

Answer (score 2):

To be explicit, let's make some assumptions and go from there. Assumptions:

- During each of the two periods the publication rate 'r' is constant (possibly different between periods.
- Data from the two periods is independent.
- Data is drawn iid.
- The deviation from the rate 'r' is modeled as Gaussian noise. (easily generalized, but lets keep it simple for now)
- The variances in these Gaussians are sufficiently close to the sample variances and we can thus assume them to be equal to the sample variances. (This leaves us with one parameter families of random variables indexed by $r_1$ and $r_2$.)

Okay, suppose you had two data sets (one for each publication period) $x_j^{(1)}$ and $x^{(2)}_k$ drawn from the random variables $X^{(1)}$ and $X^{(2)}$ for every $j = 1..M$ and $k = 1..N$.

We model these random variables as $$X^{(1)} \sim r_1 + N(0,\sigma^2) \text{ and } X^{(2)} \sim r_2 + N(0,\sigma^2) $$

First, lets compute the likelihood of each of the data sets:

$$l^{(1)}(r_1) = p(x^{(1)}_1,...,x^{(1)}_M;r_1) = \prod^M_{j=1}p(x^{(1)}_j;r_1)$$ with $l^{(2)}(r_2)$ defined similarly.

From what you said, the quantity you were interested in was the probability that one of the rates was greater than the other. This can be computed, given our assumptions, as:

$$P(r_1>r_2) = \int^\infty_0\int^\infty_0 1_{r_1 > r2}l^{(1)}(r_1)l^{(2)}(r_2)dr_1dr_2.$$

Obviously, some of the assumptions can be changed according to personal taste. This generative model wouldn't make much sense if we used it actually generate new data since the normal allows for negative values of $X$, but, for these purposes, this should be a good approximation to what you're looking for, philosophical differences aside. All that is left is picking your favourite numerical methods to compute these values.

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand it fully, but might try harder :) Will this test give me significantly better results than the mentioned MWW U-Test? I have very small sample sizes, maybe only slightly more than 5 per set.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it depends on what assumptions you want to make. Since you are comparing two sets of temporal data, you could assume that each set was generated by a different constant rate of publication with some random noise. In that case, if you assume the noise is of the same type, it wouldn't be too hard to infer the 'true publication rates'. Otherwise, you could assume the form if the 'true publication rate' is a more general function of time than a constant. In this case, you would need a norm to compare the two functions. This may be more a more complicated task than what you seek.

More philosophically, why do desire to model these events statistically? The simplest test to see which period was more productive would be to average each. However, this wouldn't give you a 'probability'. To me, it seems like the [Mind Projection Fallacy](http://lesswrong.com/lw/oi/mind_projection_fallacy/) idea is relavant here. It basically says that the events of the world aren't inherently random, but since we only have a limited information about phenomena we observe, the best thing we can do is model these phenomena probabilistically. In regards to your problem, if the phenomena you care about is publication rates, you basically know all the information during these two periods and treating them as random events doesn't make too much sense unless you are actually interested in some more convoluted phenomena (like the person's effort or production of ideas during these periods).

Comment: Sounds interesting :) However, I'm not sure if I can get an answer with this information. Indeed I want to compare publication rates, but as you say I find it more important to quantify the significance/evidence of different publication rates. I assume different rates are due to different interest in one particular topic (publications are by topic) and this interest I want to quantify. Can you help me find a probability for one rate being higher than the other?

Comment: I want to assume constant publication rates for simplicity (and not functions), since I need to communicate a rule of thumb procedure for evidence checking to non-mathematicians.

Comment: @Gerenuk:  I suggest you take into account the comments by Daniel and Michelle about what you want to accomplish using *inferential* statistics.  Based on these 2 time samples, to what are you trying to generalize?

Comment: @Rolando: If you look closely they actually avoid giving a concrete answer, but instead start a discussion by questioning the question. I'm not going to write an essay to justify all details I haven't explained yet. The question stands as it is written and you should trust that in my situation an answer like Xians is what helps me most. Objections and improvements to my analysis I can think of myself.

Comment: @Gerenuk, if you want the best possible help here, it is in your interest to try to engage with folks who are offering you constructive feedback, rather than dismissing them without substantive explanation.